# What's the example of ClassVisitor#visitTypeAnnotation and MethodVisitor#visitTypeAnnotation

Tags: java, java-8, java-bytecode-asm

I'm learning asm, and I found two interesting api

In `org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor`

```
/**
 * Visits an annotation on a type in the class signature.
 */
public AnnotationVisitor visitTypeAnnotation(int typeRef,
        TypePath typePath, String desc, boolean visible);
```

and in `org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor`

```
/**
 * Visits an annotation on a type in the method signature.
 * 
 */
public AnnotationVisitor visitTypeAnnotation(int typeRef,
        TypePath typePath, String desc, boolean visible);
```

But what's situation we will use this two method..

How can we generate an class with `an annotation on a type in the class/method signature` in java?

I try

```
 public @Z Integer testMethod(String testParam)
```

but `@Z` is still called by visitAnnotation not visitTypeAnnotation...

what's situation asm will call visitTypeAnnotation?

thx~

Comment: Does `Z` have an `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)` annotation?

Comment: @immibis Oh~~~, thx immibis, I got it.. `Type Annotation` is a new feature for Java 8, I learn some `Type Annotation` info and upgrade to Java 8,  tag  `@Target(ElementType.TYPE_USE)` to @Z it works...thank u~(I still use jdk7)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Type annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html) are a new Java 8 feature. For enabling an annotation to be used in a type context, the annotation type must itself be annotated with `@Target(`[`ElementType.TYPE_USE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html#TYPE_USE)`)` but note that when the annotation supports the target `METHOD` at the same time, a declaration like

```
public @Z Integer testMethod(String testParam)
```

is ambiguos. Afaik, the annotation will be recorded for both, the method and the return type, then. Similarly, a declaration like

```
public Integer testMethod(@Z String testParam)
```

would be ambiguous if `@Z` supports the `PARAMETER` target at the same time.

---

Examples of unique uses where *only* type annotations can occur are

```
public Integer testMethod(List<@Z String> testParam) throws @Z RuntimeException {
    return new @Z Integer(testParam.get((@Z int)0));
}
```

If you compare with the [documentation of `MethodVisitor.visitTypeAnnotation`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitTypeAnnotation(int,%20org.objectweb.asm.TypePath,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean)) you may recognize the listed possible values for `typeRef`.

In case you are wondering how a `METHOD_RECEIVER` may get annotated, it’s a new Java 8 syntax that may not be commonly known:

```
class Example {
    void instanceMethod(@Z Example this, int firstOrdinaryParameter) {
    }
}
```

In this example, the method receiver type of `instanceMethod()` is `@Z Example` rather than `Example`, though this difference has no meaning to the Java language itself.